# I want to know how to get the list of questions posted by currently logged in user in my project

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm developing one web application in java servlet and jsp as Question and Answer. Where registered users can ask questions and also answer open questions. Here, I'm storing questions asked by every user in 'question' table. I also have 'user' table which contains registered user's information. I want to know that how I get the particular question asked by particular user. I want to display questions asked by the logged in user. How can I do that? Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do your tables look like? Basically you will need a relation between the tables. Then you would do something like `SELECT * FROM question WHERE <user> = <currently logged in user>`. But this depends on your tables structure.

Comment: @feuerball database using-mysql. table structure of question table is field
q_title  varchar(255) NO NULL
q_details text  NO NULL
answer1  text
answer2  text
answer3  text
answer4  text
answer5  text
status  varchar(10)
time_details timestamp NO NULL the structure of user table is: first_name varchar(10) NO NULL
last_name  varchar(10) NO NULL
username  varchar(10) NO NULL
password  varchar(10) NO NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should choose a different table structure. At the moment you are limited to 5 answers per question and no user is linked to a question. I would create this tables (applies to MySQL databases):

**user:**

```
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

**question:**

```
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id int NOT NULL,
...,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
```

**answer:**

```
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id int NOT NULL,
question_id int NOT NULL,
...,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id),
FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES question(id)
```

This way your questions can get unlimited answers and both questions and answers are linked to a specific user. You can now select the questions of the current user with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM question
WHERE user_id = <id of the current user>
```

Comment: @feuerball.Thank you. I followed above table structure and managed to get list of particular question asked by particular user. Please also give me link to useful resource so that I will be able to build valid and flawless table structure when doing java application/project again.

Comment: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) has some tutorials for the basic SQL stuff. For your case foreign keys are important. I forgot to add them in the example but I will do now.